# nginx redirect to one page on same server

Tags: nginx, redirect

Trying to redirect to a maintainance page, but can't find a way to do this. All the documentation assumes the redirect is to another domain, but I just want to redirect to one page on the same server. Is this actually possible or do I need to set up an intermediate server with the redirect page? Seems a bit of overkill when I just want a simple redirect. While the following changes the url correctly, it simply does not work

```
server_name old_ip_address;
        return 301 $scheme:/maintenance-page
```

But the following does, but now is pointing at the wrong server:

```
server_name old_ip_address;
        return 301 $scheme://new ip address/si/home;
```

How can I redirect to just one page but on the same domain please

Comment: **DO NOT** use HTTP 301 for redirections to downtime/maintenance pages - [HTTP 301](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) means **Permanent** Redirect, so browsers will cache the redirect and keep on redirecting their users even after your website is back online. You should use [HTTP 303](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) instead (HTTP 303 is better than 302 and 307 because it requires browser to follow-up with only a `GET` request even if the original request was POST, PUT or some other verb (though changing to 303 won't solve your problem)

Comment: What version of nginx are you running? Is this your entire configuration file?

Answer (score -3):

try using an upstream?

```
upstream xxx {
    your_newsite
}
```

```
server_name old_ip_address;
        return 301 $scheme://${upstream}/si/home;
```

Comment: This is not redirecting to a new domain, redirecting to a new domain is simple, redirecting to the same domain it seems is completely impossible

Comment: try to  use `rewrite`

Comment: Had to give up with this, ran out of time and just had to deal with the emails. Problem has not been solved. Sorry for anyone that stumbles on this post, there is no solution that I could find